# Unity, Firebase Auth, CurrentUser.ProviderData IUserInfo For Provider facebook.com Has Email Property Blank

Tags: c#, android, email, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I'm fairly new to firebase but I am trying to set up a facebook login for my app. I have succeeded in following tutorials to log in to facebook and have finally managed to put together the handover of access token to firebase for a firebase account. I experimented with making changes to my facebook account to see if they were mirrored on the firebase account and of course they weren't. I discovered ProviderData and found that on my Android device I had two entries from two providers, firebase and facebook.com . I mocked up a display of the data I was after (name, email, photourl) for the two and noticed that the email in the facebook data was blank.

Hours of googling later and I still don't have a clue. The most common answer for similar problems is:

- Make sure you've requested the "email" permission. TICK
- Make sure you project is set to "one account per email address" in the firebase console. TICK

I've checked and double checked both of those every time I read them on yet another thread about a problem similar to this. When I change my settings on facebook they're not updated in firebase (duh). I need to get the updated data from somewhere and it seems ProviderData is that place. Email isn't being included in the provider data for facebook?

Here's my code. Most of it is for updating text in my UI so I can do some debugging without having to get the console working.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Facebook.Unity;


public class FBscript : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject DialogLoggedIn;
    public GameObject DialogLoggedOut;
    public GameObject DialogUsername;
    public Image DialogProfilePic;
    Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth auth;
    Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser user;

    public List<Text> displayNameText;
    public List<Text> emailText;
    public List<Text> photoURLText;
    public List<Text> userIDText;
    public List<Text> providerText;
    public Text testText;
    public List<Text> permissionsText;


    private void Awake() {
        auth = Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
        FB.Init(SetInit, OnHideUnity);
    }

    void SetInit() {
        if (FB.IsLoggedIn) {
            Debug.Log("FB is logged in");
        } else {
            Debug.Log("FB is not logged in");
        }
        DealWithFBMenus(FB.IsLoggedIn);
    }

    void OnHideUnity(bool isGameShown) {
        if (!isGameShown) {
            Time.timeScale = 0;
        } else {
            Time.timeScale = 1;
        }
    }

    public void Logout() {
        if (FB.IsLoggedIn) {
            FB.LogOut();
        }
        if (user != null) {
            auth.SignOut();
        }
        DealWithFBMenus(FB.IsLoggedIn);
    }

    public void FBlogin() {
        List<string> permissions = new List<string>();
        permissions.Add("public_profile");
        permissions.Add("email");

        FB.LogInWithReadPermissions(permissions, AuthCallBack);
    }

    void AuthCallBack(IResult result) {
        if (result.Error != null) {
            Debug.Log(result.Error);
        } else {
            if (FB.IsLoggedIn) {
                Debug.Log("FB is logged in");
            } else {
                Debug.Log("FB is not logged in");
            }
            DealWithFBMenus(FB.IsLoggedIn);
        }
    }

    void DealWithFBMenus(bool isLoggedIn) {
        DialogLoggedIn.SetActive(isLoggedIn);
        DialogLoggedOut.SetActive(!isLoggedIn);
        if (isLoggedIn) {
            FirebaseLogin();
            //This is testing to make sure the email has sufficient permissions to be sent
            FB.API("/me?fields=email", HttpMethod.GET, DisplayUsername);
            //FB.API("/me?fields=first_name", HttpMethod.GET, DisplayUsername);
            //FB.API("/me/picture?type=square&height=128&width=128", HttpMethod.GET, DisplayProfilePic);
        }
    }

    void DisplayUsername(IResult result) {
        Text Username = DialogUsername.GetComponent<Text>();

        if (result.Error == null) {
            //Username.text = "Hi there, " + result.ResultDictionary["first_name"];
            Username.text = result.ResultDictionary["email"].ToString();
        } else {
            Debug.Log(result.Error);
        }
    }

    /*
    void DisplayProfilePic(IGraphResult result) {
        if (result.Texture != null) {
            Image ProfilePic = DialogProfilePic.GetComponent<Image>();
            ProfilePic.sprite = Sprite.Create(result.Texture, new Rect(0, 0, 128, 128), new Vector2());
        }
    }
    */

    void FirebaseLogin() {

        ///ON SCREEN DEBUGGING
        foreach (Text permissionText in permissionsText) {
            permissionText.text = "";
        }
        int z = 0;
        foreach (string permission in AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken.Permissions) {
            permissionsText[z].text = permission;
            z += 1;
        }
        ///
        ///
        ///



        Firebase.Auth.Credential credential = Firebase.Auth.FacebookAuthProvider.GetCredential(AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken.TokenString);
        auth.SignInWithCredentialAsync(credential).ContinueWith(task => {
            if (task.IsCanceled) {
                Debug.LogError("SignInWithCredentialAsync was canceled.");
                return;
            }
            if (task.IsFaulted) {
                Debug.LogError("SignInWithCredentialAsync encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
                return;
            }

            Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser user = task.Result;
            Debug.LogFormat("User signed in successfully: {0} ({1})",
                user.DisplayName, user.UserId);

            //
            //
            //THIS IS ALL PURELY ON SCREEN DEBUGGING.
            //
            //
            if (user != null) {
                Debug.Log("a");
                List<Firebase.Auth.IUserInfo> providerData = user.ProviderData as List<Firebase.Auth.IUserInfo>;
                Debug.Log(providerData.Count);
                Debug.Log(providerData[0].DisplayName);
                displayNameText[0].text = providerData[0].DisplayName;
                emailText[0].text = providerData[0].Email;
                if (providerData[0].PhotoUrl != null) {
                    photoURLText[0].text = providerData[0].PhotoUrl.ToString();
                    StartCoroutine(SetupProfilePicture(providerData[0].PhotoUrl.ToString()));
                } else {
                    photoURLText[0].text = "";
                }
                userIDText[0].text = providerData[0].UserId;
                providerText[0].text = providerData[0].ProviderId;

                int i = 0;
                foreach (Firebase.Auth.IUserInfo profile in user.ProviderData) {
                    if (displayNameText.Count >= i + 1) {
                        displayNameText[i].text = profile.DisplayName;
                        emailText[i].text = profile.Email;
                        if (profile.PhotoUrl != null) {
                            photoURLText[i].text = profile.PhotoUrl.ToString();
                        }
                        userIDText[i].text = profile.UserId;
                        providerText[i].text = profile.ProviderId;
                        i += 1;
                    }
                }
                testText.text = i.ToString();
            } else {
                Debug.Log("b");
                displayNameText[0].text = user.DisplayName;
                emailText[0].text = user.Email;
                if (user.PhotoUrl != null) {
                    photoURLText[0].text = user.PhotoUrl.ToString();
                    StartCoroutine(SetupProfilePicture(user.PhotoUrl.ToString()));
                } else {
                    photoURLText[0].text = "";
                }
                userIDText[0].text = user.UserId;
            }
            ///
            ///
            ///
        });
    }

    IEnumerator SetupProfilePicture(string givenURL) {
        WWW www = new WWW(givenURL);
        yield return www;
        DialogProfilePic.sprite = Sprite.Create(www.texture, new Rect(0, 0, www.texture.width, www.texture.height), new Vector2(0, 0));
    }
}
```